# How can I install .run file?

Tags: 14.10, xampp

Hi I'm trying to install xampp-linux-1.8.3-5-installer.run on Ubuntu. I tried chmod +x command but it doesn't respond anything. I also tried using sudo but it doesn't make any different. That package also doesn't respond although I double clicked on it. I downloaded that installer using chrome.

Answer (score 2):

`chmod +x xampp-linux-1.8.3-5-installer.run` will grant the file executable permission.

Then `./xampp-linux-1.8.3-5-installer.run` will execute the `.run` file.

You might have just entered `xampp-linux-1.8.3-5-installer.run` into the terminal without the `./`, which does nothing usually

Comment: you should avoid `sudo` unless you really trust the installer and should simply try `./xampp-linux-1.8.3-5-installer.run`

Comment: Whoops, yeah don't use `sudo` until it gives you some kind of permission error. I tend to use `sudo` on everything I have to install 'cause it'll usually give me one of those errors, but that's just me

Comment: yeah it works now, I missed ./. Thank u guys but there is another question, sry for multiple questions. I am trying to install prozilla-1.3.7.3, but there are some prblems. It says "configure: error: **A (n)curses library was not found. The program needs ncurses to run, Ncurses is freely available at : ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu **" when I type ./configure command and make command does not work.

Comment: And I just downloaded and installed ncurses-5.7 but it does not change.

Comment: And I typed 'wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu' to install as the error line said but it says No such file 'gnu'.

Comment: You could install ncurses using Ubuntu's package manager, but I'm not sure which ncurses package it would be. But if you do want to install it from the tar, there's a readme file. Skim through it. (Most U/Linux distribution software will have these files). It'll tell you that install instructions are in the `INSTALL` file, which basically says you have to enter `./configure` first, then `make` to compile and install ncurses for you

Comment: That's because that command tried downloading the directory `gnu` at the server of `ftp.gnu.org`. You needed `wget ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/ncurses/ncurses-5.9.tar.gz`. You can click on that ftp link to browse through their directory to see what you can use `wget` on